# How can I add JQuery to magento 2 custom module

Tags: magento-2.1, jquery

I have `test.js` file like below

```
function Calculation(){

//area calculation
    var width = document.getElementById('width').value;
    var height = document.getElementById('height').value;

    var area = (parseInt(width) * parseInt(height) / 1000000);
    document.getElementById("area").innerHTML = "Area : " + area; 

    //circumeference calculation
    var width = document.getElementById('width').value;
    var height = document.getElementById('height').value;

    var circumeference = (2*(parseInt(width) + parseInt(height))/1000);
    document.getElementById("circumeference").innerHTML = "Circumeference : " + circumeference;
```

and I have import this file in my layout `example_index_index.xml` file head like below.

```
<script src="Test2_Helloworld::js/test.js"/>
```

Instead of JavaScript can I use JQuery?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to add JQuery externally in Magento2 you just need to load it and Magento 2 have requirejs-config-js concept to use custom js.

So you can follow that ,placed your custom js file (Ex - test.js) into your custom module like , **Vendor_Modulename/view/frontend/web/js/test.js**

create **requirejs-config.js** in your **Vendor_Modulename/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js** and write below code in it .

```
    var config = {
    "map": {
        "*": {
            "Test": "Vendor_Modulename/js/test"
        }
        shim: {
             'Test': {
                  deps: ['jquery']
              }
       } 
}

};
```

Now go to the your template file , and add **below code at the bottom of .phtml file:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     require.config({
     waitSeconds: 0 
     });
    //function for load test slider
    require([ 'jquery', 'test'], function(){
            alert("goes here");
     });
</script>
```

> So here we have loaded jQuery first and then loaded your custom js
>   where you can use any function of jQuery.

Hope it helps :

Comment: @Hemal updated the answer please check again !!!

Comment: Is the shim section of `requirejs-config.js` necessary here? Isn't require aware of the dependency due to `require([ 'jquery', 'test']`?

Comment: test.js file like this is that the error do i need to include something there -function Calculation(){
    alert("working")
}

Answer (score 1):

jQuery library is already added to M2. You can use it like below in your template file.

```
require(['jquery'], function($){ 
    var width = jQuery('#width').val();
    var height = jQuery('#height').val();
    var area = (parseInt(width) * parseInt(height) / 1000000);
    jQuery("#area").html("Area : " + area);

    //circumeference calculation
    var width = jQuery('#width').val();
    var height = jQuery('#height').val();

    var circumeference = (2*(parseInt(width) +         parseInt(height))/1000);
    jQuery("#circumeference").html("Circumeference : " + circumeference);
});
```

Comment: when i change the value of drop down its not change the area and circumfurence